# wia adf capturing only part of page

Tags: .net, wpf, wia

I have an interesting issue by one of my clients.

When scanning with WIA using the ADF, I get only a small part of each page as the image, about 2 by 4 inches. Instead of 8.5 by 11.

The same code on my pc/scanner works just fine. Also by this client it works fine on the flatbed. The issue crops (pun intended) up only with the ADF.

I haven't the foggiest idea where to start looking.

I'm posting here an iteration of the `WIA Item` properties i can get in code:.

> 0:Access Rights=3
>
> 1:Bits Per Channel=1
>
> 2:Bits Per Pixel=1
>
> 3:Brightness=0
>
> 4:Buffer Size=65535
>
> 5:Bytes Per Line=108
>
> 6:Channels Per Pixel=1
>
> 7:Color Profile Name=sRGB Color Space Profile.icm
>
> 8:Compression=0
>
> 9:Contrast=0
>
> 10:Current Intent=0
>
> 11:Data Type=0
>
> 12:Filename extension=BMP
>
> 13:Format={B96B3CAB-0728-11D3-9D7B-0000F81EF32E}
>
> 14:Full Item Name=0001\Root\Scan
>
> 15:Horizontal Extent=850
>
> 16:Horizontal Resolution=300
>
> 17:Horizontal Start Position=0
>
> 18:Item Flags=532483
>
> 19:Item Name=Scan
>
> 20:Item Size=0
>
> 21:Media Type=2
>
> 22:Number of Lines=1400
>
> 23:Orientation=0
>
> 24:Photometric Interpretation=0
>
> 25:Pixels Per Line=850
>
> 26:Planar=0
>
> 27:Preferred Format={B96B3CAB-0728-11D3-9D7B-0000F81EF32E}
>
> 28:Rotation=0
>
> 29:Threshold=128
>
> 30:Vertical Extent=1400
>
> 31:Vertical Resolution=300
>
> 32:Vertical Start Position=0

And these are the properties for the `WIA Device`:

> 0:BaudRate=
>
> 1:Description=Canon D1300/MF6700
>
> 2:DeviceKey=D1300
>
> 3:Document Handling Capabilities=39
>
> 4:Document Handling Select=1
>
> 5:Document Handling Status=34
>
> 6:Driver Version=3.0.0.0
>
> 7:Firmware Version=1.00
>
> 8:Full Item Name=0001\Root
>
> 9:Hardware Configuration=0
>
> 10:Horizontal Bed Size=8500
>
> 11:Horizontal Optical Resolution=300
>
> 12:Horizontal Sheet Feed Size=8500
>
> 13:Item Category={F193526F-59B8-4A26-9888-E16E4F97CE10}
>
> 14:Item Flags=76
>
> 15:Item Name=Root
>
> 16:Manufacturer=Canon
>
> 17:Max Scan Time=3600000
>
> 18:Minimum Horizontal Sheet Feed Size=10
>
> 19:Minimum Vertical Sheet Feed Size=10
>
> 20:Name=Canon D1300/MF6700 (Network: 180CACDB1143)
>
> 21:Page Height=14000
>
> 22:Page Size=2
>
> 23:Page Width=8500
>
> 24:Pages=1
>
> 25:PnP ID
>   String=\?\root#canon_mf_network#0000#{6bdd1fc6-810f-11d0-bec7-08002be2092f}
>
> 26:Port=CNMFNPSCAN_180CACDB1143
>
> 27:Preview=0
>
> 28:Remote Device ID=
>
> 29:Server=local
>
> 30:Sheet Feeder Registration=1
>
> 31:Show preview control=1
>
> 32:STI Driver Version=3
>
> 33:STI Generic Capabilities=17
>
> 34:Type=65537
>
> 35:UI Class ID={E2DCAEBD-D51C-413d-86A5-685670AA9C04}
>
> 36:Unique Device ID={6BDD1FC6-810F-11D0-BEC7-08002BE2092F}\0001
>
> 37:User Name=ABC-PC\ABC
>
> 38:Vertical Bed Size=14000
>
> 39:Vertical Optical Resolution=300
>
> 40:Vertical Sheet Feed Size=14000
>
> 41:WIA Version=2.0

If it helps any, then the possible list of DPI resolution does not seem to work correctly either. I get the subtype as a `RangeSubType` with the following properties

Min:50,Max:600,Step:1

Which I believe is incorrect...

Comment: any ideas anybody? im open for any directions. again this happening (meanwhile) only by one specific scanner. thanks!

Comment: anyone maybe? this is very important for me. and i cant seem to find any similar question anywhere. thanks!

Comment: Hi, did you solve it somehow?

Comment: yes. though probably via twain. im not sure. also most of my apps today are web based so its less relevant.

Comment: Hi. I'm encountering this issue again. Now also with the flatbed. Any ideas?

Comment: I had exactly this issue just with Cannon printers. HP was ok. It was solved by setting up 6151 and 6152 properties.

Comment: That was it!! after years and years!! please make this an answer so I can give you due credit! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had exactly this issue just with Cannon printers. HP was ok.
It was solved by setting up **6151** and **6152** properties.